# Do I have to add "<%@ Register assembly=" to every page?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I upgraded DevExpress components but in my application I have to change every `<%@ Register assembly="Dev....... version=....` line in every page.

Is there any way to do this without putting same lines to every page?
Can't I do this in web.config page?

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v10.1, Version=10.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" 
Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" TagPrefix="dx" %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yup, see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add last state of web.config:

```
<system.web>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" theme="OrderDefault" clientIDMode="AutoID">
    <controls>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"     assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"                       tagPrefix="asp" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid"                 assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"                tagPrefix="dx"/>
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Xpo"                               assembly="DevExpress.Xpo.v10.2.Web, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"                          tagPrefix="dx" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Data.Linq"                         assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.2.Linq, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"                         tagPrefix="dx" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.Export"           assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v10.2.Export, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"          tagPrefix="dx" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors"                   assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"                  tagPrefix="dx" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView"                  assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"                 tagPrefix="dx"/>
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxPopupControl"              assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"                              tagPrefix="dx" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSiteMapControl"            assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"                              tagPrefix="dx"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"                    assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"                                  tagPrefix="asp" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"     assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"                       tagPrefix="asp" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxNewsControl"               assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"                              tagPrefix="dx" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxPanel"                     assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"                              tagPrefix="dx" />
    </controls>
</pages>
</system.web>
```

[image]