# asp.net calling code inline not working

Tags: asp.net

In my code behind, I can do the following in the onload:

```
string x = Fmg.Cti.UI.Utilities.Classes.ResourceController.ReadResourceValue("Riblet", "Riblet_Chicklet1_Button_text");
```

This works without issue.

In my aspx page (I didn't remove the code from the onload), I put this:

```
<%= Fmg.Cti.UI.Utilities.Classes.ResourceController.ReadResourceValue("Riblet", "Riblet_Chicklet1_Button_text")%>
```

When I do, I got an error:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Cti' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Fmg' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I had this (or something quite similar) working. I don't know how I broke it.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: can you show your aspx markup?

Answer (score 2):

You need to register the assemblies you're using in your page as well (just like usings in your code behind). See [Do I have to add "<%@ Register assembly=" to every page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660400/do-i-have-to-add-register-assembly-to-every-page)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that namespace imported?  For asp.net you can do something like the following to make namespaces available for inline coding.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Fmg.Cti.UI.Utilities.Classes" %>
```

You can make namespaces generally available to all of your asp.net pages for inline coding by adding the namespaces into the web.config

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        ...
        <add namespace="Fmg.Cti.UI.Utilities.Classes" />
        ...
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```