# DevExpress CSS "dx:"

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am a new to CSS world, so please help me out to figure it out.
I have tried to use a sample css from DevExpress ASP MVC demo and I have received a below error msg. I have two questions regarding this error msg.

1. What do I need add to resolve this error?
2. What deos "dx:" means?

By the way, I am getting "Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'dx' in visual studio 2010.

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'dx:Head'.

Source Error:

```
Line 14:     <title></title>
Line 15:     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="CustomTopHeadHolder" runat="server" />
Line 16:     <dx:Head ID="Head" runat="server" />
Line 17:     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="CustomHeadHolder" runat="server" />
```

Comment: >>I have tried to use a sample css from DevExpress ASP MVC demo and I have received a below error msg.<< Where have you got this code snippet? There is no such DX control... It looks like to the standard <head> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "dx" is just a tag to tell it is a DevExpress Command. For the error message try registering the tags you are going to use. 
For example if you are planning to use a ASPxNavBar then you will have to add this

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxNavBar" TagPrefix="dx" %>
```

Note this is for the Version 10.2.6. You will have to add the appropriate one for your project

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a namespace prefix. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660400/do-i-have-to-add-register-assembly-to-every-page) question for guidance.